# Weird undesired inputs when not doing anything

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell, events

This is quite the open-ended question and I don't really have any idea on how to approach it, but here it goes:

It feels like my laptop (Dell P7510 on ubuntu 20.04) is somehow receiving undesired inputs even when nothing is touched. Symptoms:

- Controls keep popping up in full screen mode in various players (online or not)
- Mouse cursor pops up in VLC full screen (but does not move)
- Keyboard backlighting keeps fading off (expected if no user inputs for some seconds) and lighting up again.
- This happens often/systematically, but no perceivable regularity to it.

What I have tried (with no success):

- Disabling trackpad
- Disabling trackpoint with `xinput`
- Checked that it also happens when laptop is not charging

I can't check right now but it seems like my desktop has the same issue even though it runs 18.04 and obviously has different hardware connected to it: no trackpad/trackpoint (have tried disconnecting mouse), no wifi, no charger.

I don't really now where to even start looking for what might be sending those weird events, so I am going a bit on a limb here, hoping that you might have some interesting suggestions.